# 'RangeIndex' object is not callable

Tags: python, dataframe

Index cannot be found when repetitive variable creation is applied.
I'm not sure how to filter it with 2 dataframes.

#### code

```py
index_100 = globals()['df_n{}'.format(i)]['value'].index(100)
```

#### error

```
'RangeIndex' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find 101th element in index, you need indexing with `[]`

```py
index_100 = globals()['df_n{}'.format(i)]['value'].index[100]
```

Comment: index_100 = globals()['df_n{}'.format(i)]['value'].index[globals()['df_n{}'.format(i)]==100]   


                                          
Thanks for the reply. I have additional questions.
I get an error "too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed", but the original data is [11485 rows x 1 columns]
So there seems to be no problem. May I know the cause?

Comment: @yunahwang `globals()['df_n{}'.format(i)]==100` return a boolean DataFrame while dataframe is 2D dimensional numpy array. You cann't use it as the index. If your original problem is solved, you can click the accepted button.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So how do I get the index when the value is 100?

Comment: @yunahwang Add the column.

Comment: oh problem solved, thanks for the help
I am editing it like below
`index_100 = globals()['df_n{}'.format(i)]['value'].index[globals()['df_n{}'.format(i)]['value']==100]`

--> Int64Index([11317, 11318, 11319, 11320, 11321, 11322, 11323, 11324, 11325,
             11326,
             ...
             11475, 11476, 11477, 11478, 11479, 11480, 11481, 11482, 11483,
             11484]